# How to access form controls from within custom control

Tags: vb.net

OK it's little strange for me. I never used something like this. I have a form named **VBProject** It has two TextBoxes and one custom control named **MyControl** which is created in another project.
**MyControl**'s project has a form inside, named **Form3**. When My control is loaded it needs to find all controls in my **VBProject** and add them into a **listbox** which is in **Form3**. Then Show the **Form3**. In the end **ListView** need to shows name and text of  textboxes but it shows nothing. Here are my codes:

> MyControl's Load_Event:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
MessageBox.Show("Control Count:" + Me.Controls.Count.ToString)
For Each MyObject In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf MyObject Is TextBox Then
        MessageBox.Show("Found a textbox")
        Dim lviNew As New ListViewItem
        lviNew.Text = i.ToString()
        lviNew.SubItems.Add(MyObject.Name)
        lviNew.SubItems.Add(MyObject.Text)
        Form3.SetVal(lviNew)
        i += 1
    End If
Next
Form3.Show()
```

> SetVal Function in Form3

```
Public Sub SetVal(ByVal lviNew As ListViewItem)
    lstName.Items.Add(lviNew)
End Sub
```

Picture of project

[image]

A:VBProject-B:MYControl Execute-C:MyControl's Project's Form3

I hope explained it well. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please explain what is **not** working? I guess the list view does not show anything, but it's a guess.

Comment: You are right. That's my problem exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by "When MyControl is loaded"? Where is the code located? In the UserControls load event?
By the way, you can add images to your question, so you don't need an external source.

Comment: Yes codes are in Load event of control. So I think codes will be activated when I load form which is using my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the controls of the form a custom control is located on by using

```
Me.ParentForm.Controls
```

The controls of the parent which could for example be a panel can be accessed by

```
Me.Parent.Controls
```

You used `Me.Controls` which refers to the controls owned by the custom control itself.

I don't know exactly, but you might get problems when using this in the load event of the control, because other controls of the parent form might be loaded after the custom control.